# How to fix overlapping tick labels for svg legend using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend, linear-gradients, continuous

I have an color legend created using linear gradient and D3 concept. The issue currently I am facing is that the ticks labels of the legend gets overlapped.

I have to show the Min and Max values all the time and extra ticks as well.

I have shared code snippet and also the JS fiddle. I tried few things but nothing seems to work for me.

```js
const itemColor = [{
    offset: 0.0,
    color: "#ff0000"
  },
  {
    offset: 0.1,
    color: "#ffff00"
  },
  {
    offset: 0.4,
    color: "#00ff00"
  },
  {
    offset: 0.5,
    color: "#00ffff"
  },
  {
    offset: 0.8,
    color: "#0000ff"
  },
  {
    offset: 1.0,
    color: "#ff00ff"
  }
];

const svg = d3.select("svg");

let min = 1918
let max = 3780
 
const linearColorScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([min, max]).range([0, 150]); 
const id = "linear-gradient-0";

const linearGradient = svg.append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "linear-gradient-1")
  .attr("x1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "100%")
  .attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("y2", "0%");

// append the color
linearGradient
  .selectAll("stop")
  .data(itemColor)
  .enter()
  .append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(data) {
    return linearColorScale(min + (data.offset * (max - min))) / 1.5 + "%";
  })
  .attr("stop-color", function(data) {
    return data.color;
  });

// draw the rectangle and fill with gradient
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 108)
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .style("fill", "url(#linear-gradient-1)");
  
 svg.append("text").text("Linear Scale").attr("y", 93)

// create tick
svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(10,130)").call(d3.axisBottom(linearColorScale).tickValues( linearColorScale.ticks( 3 ).concat( linearColorScale.domain() ) ));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1g7qmh3y/2/

Answer (score 2):

If you are both a) constrained in the space you can use, and b) must show the extent of the domain plus the inner ticks; then you can consider another axis on top of the colour bar. This way you show the min/ max on the top axis and the intermediate ticks on the bottom axis. See below:

```js
const itemColor = [ { offset: 0.0, color: "#ff0000" }, { offset: 0.1, color: "#ffff00" }, { offset: 0.4, color: "#00ff00" }, { offset: 0.5, color: "#00ffff" }, { offset: 0.8, color: "#0000ff" }, { offset: 1.0, color: "#ff00ff" } ];

const svg = d3.select("svg");

let min = 1918
let max = 3780
 
const linearColorScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([min, max]).range([0, 150]); 
const id = "linear-gradient-0";

const linearGradient = svg.append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "linear-gradient-1")
  .attr("x1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "100%")
  .attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("y2", "0%");

// append the color
linearGradient
  .selectAll("stop")
  .data(itemColor)
  .enter()
  .append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(data) {
    return linearColorScale(min + (data.offset * (max - min))) / 1.5 + "%";
  })
  .attr("stop-color", function(data) {
    return data.color;
  });

// draw the rectangle and fill with gradient
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 108)
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .style("fill", "url(#linear-gradient-1)");
  
// move it up slightly to accommodate upper axis
svg.append("text").text("Linear Scale").attr("y", 73)

// create lower ticks - removed domain of scale and removed outer ticks
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,130)")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(linearColorScale)
    .tickValues( linearColorScale.ticks(3))
    .tickSizeOuter(0)
  );

// create another axis for upper ticks
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,103)")
  .call(d3.axisTop(linearColorScale)
    .tickValues(linearColorScale.domain()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

Comment: Your solution looks fine for temporary solution but I may have an requirement in future where I would need to display the ticks in single bar . I think in that case one workaround may be show the ticks values bit slanting and not straight so that it do not consume more space and hence avoid overlapping, just my thought though.

Comment: @Eric If you want to angle the label text - see here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4403522. Another option - if you can consider a `min` that is a bit smaller it won't be scrunched up against the first tick.